# WSO2 enable transport from Carbon Application

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

To use some transports in WSO2 esb you have to edit the `ESB_HOME/conf/axis2.xml`

Like in [this](http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/use-mail-transport-esb-convert-soap-message-plain-text-mail/) tutorial you have to uncomment the email transport.

Is there a way to configure a transport in Carbon application developed in WSO2 Developer Studio, without editting the axis2.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a request comes to ESB it first hits to axis2 level. Then the transport is selected from axis2 and then request goes to synapse level.So any way we need to edit the axis2.xml to enable any transport for that request.